# Зависает компиляция игры после интеграции сторонних SDK

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

У меня проблема, не могу скомпилировать игру под андроид, раньше всё прекрасно работало, а сейчас, после интеграции SDK фейсбука и еще нескольких файлов, юнити проверяет наличие сдк, ндк доходит до сцен и замирает на моменте 'Sceane 0: Game' в самом начале и ничего больше не происходит, юнька тупо зависает.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас именно самая первая сцена не загружается и зависает?

Возможно в **Awake** есть проблемы или что то подгружается много раз от этого и запуск сложный, просмотрите все ваши выходы **Awake** и **Start** если их не много, советую провести отладку с помощью **Debug.Log** в этих местах и увидеть в каком месте идут тормоза если возможно остановить игру.

Если это было только после интеграции **SDK** то возможно где то Вы инициализируетесь не корректно или бесконечно много раз, возможно у вас создаются бесконечно много объектов этих **SDK** либо иные объекты.

Если метод отладки с **Debug.Log** вам не подходит попробуйте закомментировать те же **Awake** и **Start** методы которые подходят под описание выше.